# Select elements of list in Manipulate

Tags: list-manipulation, manipulate

How can I select elements of a list of strings `{"a", "b", "c"}` using Manipulate, such that when a checkbox is unchecked, only the other elements are presented?

```
    Manipulate[ 
     {"a", "b", "c"}, 
     Control[{"a", {True, False}}],
     Control[{"b", {True, False}}],
     Control[{"c", {True, False}}]
    ]
```

Comment: Related question: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/129667/3066

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using a custom function to specify a CheckboxBar in the Manipulate, you can do the following:

```
list = {"a", "b", "c"};
Manipulate[selected, {{selected, {}}, CheckboxBar[#, list] &}]
```

You can still change the initial value like with other control specifications by replacing the {} with {"a"} or list or such.